# Navigation bar being hidden behind content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

This is the init method for a UINavigationController. I think I must be doing this wrong.

```
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.viewController];


    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(done)];
    self.viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
    self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

    self.mediaScrollView = [[MediaScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.mediaScrollView.touchDelegate = self;
    self.mediaScrollView.fullScreenDelegate = self;
    [self.viewController.view addSubview:self.mediaScrollView];


}
return self;
```

}

The mediaScrollView is going in front of my navigation bar. It should be appearing behind the navigation bar.

This is the method for calling it:

```
self.mediaVC = [[PDMediaViewController alloc] init];
    self.mediaVC.mediaScrollView.manualMedia = YES;
    self.mediaVC.mediaScrollView.mediaDelegate = self;
    self.mediaVC.mediaScrollView.currentMediaItem = 0;

    self.mediaVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.mediaVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: don't subclass UINavigationController (unless you *really* know what you're doing!)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you don't subclass `UINavigationController`. Instead, you create subclasses of `UIViewControllers` and then use a normal `UINavigationController` instance to handle your view controllers.

```
MyViewController *firstViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
```

Check out the navigation controller template in XCode.

Comment: So in the class where I call it, I have to give it properties like a translucent navigation bar every time?

Comment: Yes. Or in the view controller's viewWill/DidDisplay method.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not subclass UINavigationController!**

> The UINavigationController class implements a specialized view controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. **This class is not intended for subclassing**. Instead, you use instances of it as-is in situations where you want your application’s user interface to reflect the hierarchical nature of your content. This navigation interface makes it possible to present your data efficiently and also makes it easier for the user to navigate that content.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html